# Is there a way to add a custom class template to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

Here's the scenario.  I often create classes that follow a certain pattern.  All classes extend a base abstract class (out of my control) with certain methods I wish to always override, including the constructor.  I'd like to rightclick on my package name, click New, and then click "Foo Class".  I'd then have a class added to my project, but using the "Foo" template instead of the standard class template.  I understand I can change the class template, but I don't want to change it for all classes.  Is this possible without writing a full blown extension?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the editor template to create a new template and use that.

Go to Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates and create your template there.

Then create a new class file and apply your template.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. What you'd like to achieve needs writing an eclipse plugin.

I'd suggest setting up a Template (at Preferences | Java | Editor | Templates) and giving it a short useful name describing your scenario. Whenever you'd want to write an additional template class, you could create a new class, press Ctrl+A, Del (select all and remove), then type "name Ctrl+Space" and have your template there as configured.

ps. I'd really review your requirement, can't think of a valid approach at the moment which would require writing many similar classes without a valid way to remove the code duplication you are just about to introduce.

Comment: I want certain methods overridden by default and ready for me to customize.  I'd also like a starter constructor that I would then modify.  I'm just saving me some keystrokes on things I'm going to do anyway.

Comment: wouldn't an abstract base class work in that case? you'd specify those certain methods abstract and add the constructor you'd like to use. subclasses would be required to implement the abstract methods and also explicitly invoke the superclass constructor off it has one defined.

Comment: After rereading it, my original explanation was misleading.  I meant to say something of the effect that I'm not implementing a common interface.  I do have a common base abstract class.  But I want to override the same methods each time.